# Multiple Geo_point [Elasticsearch]

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints

i am creating a list of geo position in elasticsearch wonder how to extract number of geopoints and also get the location

```
  PUT /routes
{
    "mappings":{
        "properties":{
            "name":{
                "type":"text"
            },
            "location":{
                "type": "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /routes/_doc/1
{
    "name":"Route 1",
    "location":[
            "18.319410,-64.703247",
            "34.297878,-83.824066"
        ]
}
```

wonder how to get the number of location is 1 or 2 or more
and each location

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create another field `nbLocations`which would contain the size of the `location` array?

Comment: sorry i dont understand could you give me some example?? and my location will be variable such as maybe 0 or 50 locations

Comment: Maybe you can explain how you're using your data? What queries are you going to run?

Comment: I using it to the data to plot a route that I going to travel. I will be query the route for the day. like point a and point b, in between will have some extra point

Comment: Why not using a [`LineString geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#input-structure) which is exactly for this purpose?

Comment: @Val ok i understand what you mean will go try it thanks